# Delphi how to avoid an uninitialized variable in chain methods

Tags: delphi, delphi-10.2-tokyo

I'm trying to build an API, but I'm stopped at the following problem:

Here is all the code to simulate the problem

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls, System.Rtti;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    btnWorking: TButton;
    btnNotWorking: TButton;
    procedure btnWorkingClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure btnNotWorkingClick(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

  TEntityManagerWhereExpression = record
    FCondition: Boolean;
  end;

  TEntityManagerWhereExpressionFnc = reference to function(): TEntityManagerWhereExpression;

  TEntityExpressionOperation = record
  private
    FCondition: Boolean;
  public
    class operator Implicit(A: TEntityExpressionOperation): TEntityManagerWhereExpression;
    class operator Equal(A, B: TEntityExpressionOperation): TEntityExpressionOperation;
    class operator BitwiseAnd(A, B: TEntityExpressionOperation): TEntityExpressionOperation;
  end;

  TEntityExpression<T> = record
  private
    FValue: TValue;
  public
    class operator Implicit(A: string): TEntityExpression<T>;
    class operator Implicit(A: TEntityExpression<T>): string;

    class operator Equal(A, B: TEntityExpression<T>): TEntityExpressionOperation;
  end;

  IMyEntity = interface
    ['{BE3EE808-47BB-4E83-94BA-ABC9B3D861F2}']
    function GetNome: TEntityExpression<string>;
    property Nome: TEntityExpression<string> read GetNome;
  end;

  TMyEntity = class(TInterfacedObject, IMyEntity)
    function GetNome: TEntityExpression<string>;
  end;

  IManager = interface
    ['{DE38CC69-069F-48F9-A9A4-E93BA0A87E5F}']
    function produce(out myEntity: IMyEntity): IManager;
    procedure Show(const exp: TEntityManagerWhereExpression);
  end;

  TMyManager = class(TInterfacedObject, IManager)
  public
    function produce(out myEntity: IMyEntity): IManager;
    procedure Show(const exp: TEntityManagerWhereExpression);
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.btnNotWorkingClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  my: IMyEntity;
begin
  TMyManager.Create().produce(my).Show(my.Nome = 'Paulo');
end;

procedure TForm1.btnWorkingClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  my: IMyEntity;
  MyManager: IManager;
begin
  MyManager := TMyManager.Create().produce(my) as IManager;
  MyManager.Show(my.Nome = 'Paulo 2');
end;

{ TMyManager }

function TMyManager.produce(out myEntity: IMyEntity): IManager;
begin
  Result := Self;
  myEntity := TMyEntity.Create;
end;

procedure TMyManager.Show(const exp: TEntityManagerWhereExpression);
begin
  if exp.FCondition then
    ShowMessage('true')
  else
    ShowMessage('false');
end;

{ TEntityExpressionOperation }

class operator TEntityExpressionOperation.BitwiseAnd(A, B: TEntityExpressionOperation): TEntityExpressionOperation;
begin
  Result.FCondition := A.FCondition and B.FCondition;
end;

class operator TEntityExpressionOperation.Equal(A, B: TEntityExpressionOperation): TEntityExpressionOperation;
begin
  Result.FCondition := False;
end;

class operator TEntityExpressionOperation.Implicit(A: TEntityExpressionOperation): TEntityManagerWhereExpression;
begin
  Result.FCondition := A.FCondition;
end;

{ TEntityExpression<T> }

class operator TEntityExpression<T>.Equal(A, B: TEntityExpression<T>): TEntityExpressionOperation;
begin
  Result.FCondition := A.FValue.AsString = B.FValue.AsString;
end;

class operator TEntityExpression<T>.Implicit(A: string): TEntityExpression<T>;
begin
  Result.FValue := A;
end;

class operator TEntityExpression<T>.Implicit(A: TEntityExpression<T>): string;
begin
  Result := A.FValue.AsString;
end;

{ TMyEntity }

function TMyEntity.GetNome: TEntityExpression<string>;
begin
  Result := 'Paulo';
end;

end.
```

The problem is in the code snippet

```
TMyManager.Create (). Produces (my) .Show (my.Name = 'Paul');
```

where the variable my was not initialized, since the code snippet

```
my.name = 'Paulo'
```

is checked before

```
produce
```

the problem does not occur when I call it this way:

```
var
   my: IMyEntity;
   MyManager: IManager;
begin
   MyManager: = TMyManager.Create (). Produces (my) as IManager;
   MyManager.Show (my.Name = 'Paul 2');
```

because the variable my is initialized before calling the Show method

how can I prevent the variable my from being used before it is initialized?

**Can someone help me solve this problem? thank you so much**

Comment: Which ORM are you using? Did you ask on their website for support?I even wonder how the "working user code" may work since the entityManagerQueryBuilder variable is never set before use... I'm confused by so much confusion in your samples...

Comment: @ArnaudBouchez I'm not using any third-party API, I'm developing my API from scratch

Comment: @DavidHeffernan What's missing in the code I have not placed? the code I put in is enough to reproduce the error, I'm not using third-party API or something, if the code is not enough, what's missing? thank you

Comment: @ArnaudBouchez I changed the code

Comment: @Passella: It may be enough **for you** to reproduce the error, but **not for us**. A lot of stuff is unknown, so if you want people to be able to help you, make a [MCVE].

Comment: @Passella - Paste the code in the question into a brand new project and then run it. You'll find out what is missing.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz the demo project only has this code, I have done another, this does not change, the problem is that the variable p is nil, and the problem is that the compiler checks p.name before anything in the first code snippet, the second works perfectly, because the variable p has already been initialized, I want to know if I can avoid this

Comment: @RudyVelthuis, ok, i will put all the code

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I changed the question by putting the codes and showing where the problem is, can anyone now help?

Comment: @RudyVelthuis I changed the question by putting the codes and showing where the problem is, can anyone now help?

Comment: [mcve] please. This isn't it. Still, fluent interfaces aren't as great as you think.

Comment: wait a moment, I'll make another example

Comment: What you posted is not a [MCVE]. It should be something other people can copy to their editor and compile and run. Even after your edits, this isn't. It is not minimal, *complete* nor *verifiable*.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis and now? thank you

Comment: @DavidHeffernan and now? thank you

Comment: Not minimal. Keep trying. Thanks.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I really not know what to do, just put this code in a new project and compile, what's missing that I'm not seeing? Can you tell me?

Comment: @Passella, much better, but still too much that distracts from the problem and is not required to demonstrate it. As David said: not minimal.

Comment: Did you follow the link? [MCVE]. Needs to be both minimal and complete.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan the code is Minimal, if i remove any line, the coe don't compile, the code need the class operator to compile, The code is Complete, juste paste in your delphi e hit F9, no changes are needed, The code is Verifiable, one button is working, the other not. Where is the fault in my question?

Comment: Code is not minimal. We don't need a form.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan and now?

Comment: This isn't going anywhere. I'm interested in trying to help you learn. It's not working.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis already solved my problem, thank you

Comment: But you've not learned how to present a problem which disappoints me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code is still far too complex, but the main problem is that

```
TMyManager.Create
```

produces an *object* (**not an interface reference!**) with a reference count of 0. If you cast it to the proper interface type, it will get a reference count of 1:

```
(TMyManager.Create as IManager)
```

So now this works:

```
procedure TForm1.btnNotWorkingClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  my: IMyEntity;
begin
  (TMyManager.Create as IManager).produce(my).Show(my.Nome = 'Paulo');
end;
```

and produces the result `'true'`.

That is why your modified code works. You assign the result of `Create` to an `IManager` before you call `Show`, and `produce` obviously doesn't change the reference count for the manager, while `Show` (indirectly) does. *I didn't try to find out how -- your code is pretty convoluted*.

Note that `Show` is not called, nor its parameter evaluated, before `produce` gets the chance to initialize `my`. That is not the problem at all.

Comment: Wonderful, really works, except that it leaves the user's final code a little more verbose. this is just the first day of my study, I believe this is just the beginning, I want something like: people: = TEntityManagerFactory
    .CreateEntityManager
    .From<IPessoa>(p)
    .Where((p.Nome = 'Paulo') and (p.Idade = 30))
     .AsList <IPessoa>;

Comment: So just define `TEntityManagerFactory .CreateEntityManager` not as a constructor, but a class function returning an `IEntityManager` interface.